# Give in andSuccumb

Tags: grammar

Is there any difference between "give in" and "succumb"? And is this correct way of using them with "provocation"?
I mean that he wanted him to get provoked by doing or saying some things

> He tried to make him to give in to provocations

> He tried to make him succumb to provocations

Comment: I want to say that "give in to provocations" and "succumb to provocations" are both technically correct, but whether they really are colloquial is hard to say without a little more context. Perhaps you could update the question with a fuller example sentence?

Comment: You're much more likely to [*succumb / give in to **temptation***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=succumb+to+temptation%2Cgive+in+to+temptation%2Csuccumb+to+provocation%2Cgive+in+to+provocation&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csuccumb%20to%20temptation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgive%20in%20to%20temptation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuccumb%20to%20provocation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgive%20in%20to%20provocation%3B%2Cc0) than to ***provocation***.  But the more colloquial (lower register) verb ***give in*** has come to dominate in recent decades.

Answer (score 3):

"Give in" implies a choice. "Succumb" suggests that someone was overwhelmed and had no choce. In many cases either might be used, with the difference in meanign beign at most one of emphasis.  If one says that

> John succumbed to cancer.

that implies that John's body was unable to ressit it, and probably that he died of it. But if one says:

> John gave in to cancer.

That suggest that John abandoned any struggle against it, mentally becoming resigned to the inevitability of the cancer.

In the case of provocations, "succumb" suggests that they had worn down a person's resistance, or perhaps angered the person to the point of unwise response. The implication is that the person had no real choice. The use of "give in" suggests that there was a choice, although the actions described might be exactly the same.

Comment: I agree ***succumb*** tends to imply being "overwhelmed" as opposed to "choosing" not to resist. I already posted an NGram link under the question showing that we're *twice* as likely today to ***give in** to temptation* rather than ***succumb** to temptation*. But focusing just on the less common context of ***provocation***, it's interesting to note that Americans use ***give in*** and ***succumb*** about equally often, whereas me and my fellow Brits still almost always use ***succumb*** when the "adversary" is more clearly identified as such (we give in to desire, but succumb to disease).

Comment: @FumbleFingers as I understand you can you it this way as "He succumbed to feminine wiles" or "He succembed to tempation". So that's to say you can use it with provocation, right?

Comment: @Boyep: Sure - you can use either ***give in*** or ***succumb*** for any of ***feminine wiles, temptation, provocation, desire, disease,...*** All I'm saying is that native Anglophones are ***more likely*** to use ***succumb*** when the context involves something *explicitly* bad (such as provocation or disease). But to be honest, if we were to look at every single instance where an Anglophone used one or the other of these terms, I'd guess that by far the biggest factor would simply be that many native speakers aren't exactly familiar with the relatively "upmarket" word ***succumb***.